# Can't see global variable from header File

Tags: c++, linker, header-files

I have two header files that rely on each other, but one header file can't see the variables from the other.

This Header files declares the map Agents

```
#pragma once
#include <agents.h>
#include "Manage_A.h"

class M_Agent : public Concurrency::agent
{
public:

    explicit M_Agent(Concurrency::ISource<int>& source, Concurrency::ITarget<wstring>& target) :
        _source(source), _target(target)
    {

    }

protected:
    void run() {
        cout << "What Would You Like to Do?\n"
            << "1. Manage Agents\n"
            << "2. See Info From Agents\n"
            << "3. Alerts\n"
            << "4. Quit\n";
        cin >> choice;
        switch (choice)
        {
            //Manage Agents
        case 1:
            Manage_A();
            run();
            break;

            //See Info from Agents
        case 2:
            cout << "INfo\n";
            run();
            break;

            //Alerts
        case 3:
            cout << "Alerts\n";
            run();
            break;

            //Quit
        case 4:
            exit(0);
            break;

            //Try again
        default:
            run();
            break;
        }

        //done();

    }

private:
    int choice{ 0 };
    Concurrency::ISource<int>& _source;
    Concurrency::ITarget<wstring>& _target;
};


extern std::map<string, M_Agent*> Agents;
extern Concurrency::overwrite_buffer<int> buffer1;
extern Concurrency::unbounded_buffer<wstring> buffer2;
```

This header contains functions using the map

```
#pragma once
#include"M_Agent.h"
#include"F_Agent.h"
#include"Variables.h"


void Create_A()
{
    system("cls");
    string name{ "" };
    int a_type{ 0 };
    std::cout << "Please Name Agent\n";
    std::cin >> name;
    while (true)
    {
        std::cout << "What Type of Agent Would You like\n"
            << "1. Main Agent\n"
            << "2. File Agent\n"
            << std::endl;
        std::cin >> a_type;

        if (std::cin.good())
        {
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            system("cls");
            std::cout << "Please enter correct choice" << std::endl;
        }
        std::cin.clear();
        std::cin.ignore();
    }
    switch (a_type)
    {
        //Create Main Agent
    case 1:
        Agents.insert(std::make_pair(name, new M_Agent(buffer1, buffer2)));
        system("cls");
        break;

        //Create File Agent
    case 2:
        F_Agents.insert(std::make_pair(name, new File_Agent(buffer1, buffer2)));
        system("cls");
        break;
    }

    return;
}
```

The problem is that the second header file says Agents is a unidentified identifier.

Comment: Insufficient data... This programmer will now exit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both header files presumably include each other. So the first file includes the second, which then tries to include the first again, but fails, since `#pragma once` is in force. As a result the necessary definitions for the second file are not available when they are needed.

To fix this you need to break this circular dependency. The best way to do this is by putting the bulk of your code into a .cpp file (instead of dumping the whole thing into headers). This will allow you to reduce the number of includes, hopefully to the point where a cross-include is no longer necessary. You may need some forward declarations to make that work though.

Answer (score 0):

Header files are mainly used for function/variable declarations, not definitions. If you were to create a source file (**.cpp**) for the definitions of the functions/variables and link that to each header file, you could possibly avoid the errors that you are experiencing.